# Двоеточие перед пояснительными словами когда можно ставить?

Tags: пунктуация, значение-слов, двоеточие, пояснительные

При наличии слов, обязательно требующих раскрытия (пояснения) значения, ставится тире: Он всеми силами души всегда желал одного — быть вполне хорошим.

Примечание. В подобных случаях при более подчеркнутом пояснении может употребляться и двоеточие:

Все они [письма] о главном: перестройке в нашей жизни (газ.);

Настроение одно: скорее добраться до дома (газ.).

Но если нет слова, обязательно требующего раскрытия (пояснения) значения, можно ли ставить двоеточие?

Например:  Было видно, как он читал: внимательно и с остановками.

И будет ли это пояснительный член предложения?

Comment: На сайте русского языка, пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила орфографии — начинайте предложение с заглавной буквы.

Answer (score 3):

Было видно, **как**  он читал: **внимательно и с остановками**.

Здесь раскрывается значение местоимения ***как***, поэтому ставится двоеточие. ***Внимательно и с остановками*** — это пояснительный член предложения, перед ним делается предупредительная пауза.